# Hair Particle, final Render shows less particles than in the viewport

Tags: particles, hair

I'm using Blender 2.8 and having a problem. I'm following a towel tutorial and I've set the number of hair particles to 1000000 and i get a result like this:

Problem

[image: Problem]

The only way it will fill up the towel is if i set the view port display at 100%

Settings

[image: Settings]

Final

[image: Final]

Every video I've seen on hair doesn't say this is necessary. Have i missed something here? is it a 2.8 bug? Thanks in advance!

Tony

Answer (score 1):

So i figured it out!!! It happens when the hair dynamics button is checked. I have unchecked it and it works as it should
[image: Fixed]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary. You are probably thinking that the view port rendered view is the same as the render. This is not so, the view port render view is exactly what you see on the view port, but when you set the amount of particles to a smaller percentage, in the final render (press F12), there will be the correct amount.

(view port rendered view)

[image]

(after rendering with F12)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting that for some reason. Please see pic
[image: Issue]

Also there is a weird message i circled that i dont see in your picture

Comment: sorry if i didnt reply properly. I couldnt attach an image via comment